# How to use the D'Alembert formula to study controllability and stability?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, control-theory, wave-equation, linear-control

I'm lost, I don't even know what the question to ask!
I'm studying a 1D wave equation, and I found the exact solution.
using the D'alembert formula so far so good. But now, I'm feeling stuck
I don't know what I can do with it! We usually try to get the
controllability or observability (which are generally equivalent in one sense).
What I am asking you is the following: do you have an idea, a comment or a reference
in which they have used the D'alembert formula's solution to prove either controllability, stability, or observability?
I know I have to read and understand the solution that I have, to be able to extract something, but I need an example for inspiration.

Thank you,
Best regards.

Comment: Would be a good idea to edit your question - specify the 1D system, and the solution you found so it can be followed.

Comment: Also consider using the `reference-request` tag

Comment: @unseen_rider ok

Comment: Ok you've added the ref-request tag, but the 1D system you're studying & solution to the system isn't specified yet.